# Settings slider images on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, preferences

I've got a settings bundle in my app, with `PSSliderSpecifier`s in it.

What sizes should those images on either side of the slider be for iPad?

(I know that for the iPhone, they should be 21 pixels squared, but they are not showing up on the iPad.)

Edit: in developer preview of 4.2, my images are back! No mod needed. Weird!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image size does not really matter but I took the habit of putting the pictures directly into the bundle instead of counting on Xcode to do the job.

Try opening the settings.bundle using the "Show Package Content" finder command, drag your pictures in there and try again.  **Don't forget to "clean all target"** after modifying the bundle.

The solution works for both iPad & iPhone

Comment: I don't understand the question. Precise "separately" please.

Comment: Did you successfully implement my solution ?

Comment: I did not get to it and I am not in front of my iMac for the next three weeks... Sorry! I was asking if I need to place the image inside the settings bundle twice, once for iPhone and once for iPad. Does Settings.bundle have an iPad only folder?

Comment: The same bundle can be used on both iPhone and iPad but I don't now how you can make it iPad specific.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to have different settings for iPhone and iPad. This is done by specifying `SupportedUserInterfaceIdioms` in the `PSSliderSpecifier` item. So if you are seeing different behavior on the different device types, try checking whether this is the reason.

Comment: Looks even more like a useful answer now.

Answer (score -1):

Pretty sure they should be the same for the iPad. Are you sure you correctly added them to your project?

Comment: I think so. They appear in my iPod settings app. Is there a specific name that I need for them to be called?